# get_post_meta is showing file url in url bar

Tags: post-meta

I want to add custom field for my product.
This field should redirect to my shop page, but its always show file url like this :

[image]

This is my code

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'livedemolink', true); ?>" title="Live Demo" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Comment: What is inside the `livedemolink`? Please add the output from `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'livedemolink', true);` to your question.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the urls in your Custom field.

This function adding http for invalid url.

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

And finally:

```
<?php
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo addhttp(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'livedemolink', true)); ?>" title="Live Demo" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```